# Meaning of や in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-や

> 美人だときく**や**友藏{ともぞう}もヒロシも身を乗り出した。
>   *When?* they heard that she was a beautiful women both 友藏 and ヒロシ leaned forward.

I have no idea what the や in bold is. It seems like it ought to be とき, but I've never seen や used to mean 'when'.

Comment: it conveys the sense of "in the instant that". i think it's more literary, but I'll leave it to a native speaker to give a fuller explanation.

Comment: I think it is mostly encountered as や否や, the meaning and grammar rule are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this や is closer to the phrase "as soon as" than "when". See the first definition (classified as 接助 = conjunctive particle) in this link. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220994/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%84/

And this usage of や is very literary. I have not ever heard that in conversation.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the informal/spoken equivalent?

Comment: "～するとすぐ" may be close to the one.

Answer (score 2):

や is short for やいなや which means "as soon as", "no sooner than".
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/4173/meaning/m0u/%E5%90%A6%E3%82%84/

So the translation becomes:
美人だときくや
As soon as they heard that she was a beautiful woman

Comment: `や is short for やいなや` <- No. や and やいなや can mean the same thing, but や is *not* short for やいなや. や, by itself, as well as the first や and the second や in **や**いな**や** , is a conjunctive particle, meaning "as soon as". http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220994/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%84/ 「1⃣［接助］動詞・動詞型活用語の終止形に付く。ある動作・作用が行われると同時に、他の動作・作用が行われる意を表す。…とすぐに。…すると。『わたしの顔を見る**や**逃げ出した』」  Saying "や is short for やいなや" is like saying "'whether' is short for 'whether or not'," or "～か is short for ～かどうか".