# When a verb in the present expresses the past, is it CORRECT to conjugate it to the past and still nothing changes?

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjugations, past

If

> あの子どもは、それを口に**入れる**や、吐き出した

is correct, is

> あの子どもは、それを口に**入れた**や、吐き出した

also correct? If yes, has the meaning changed at all?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38690/9831

Answer (score 1):

(Updated to fold in feedback from Chocolate in the comments.)

The や here <s>appears to be a shortening of</s> is equivalent to the や in the set construction ～や否【いな】や (*~ ya ina ya*, "as soon as ~").  The single や means roughly the same thing ("when ~, at the time of ~").  The や construction grammatically requires that the preceding verb be in the 連体形【れんたいけい】 (*rentaikei*, "attributive form" used to modify a noun), which in modern Japanese is identical to the so-called "plain form", "dictionary form", or 終止形【しゅうしけい】 (*shūshikei*, "terminal or conclusive form" used predicatively, such as at the end of a sentence).

Consequently, your second sample sentence would not be considered correct grammar.

When translating into English, we would indeed use the past tense form of the verb, such as *"No sooner had that kid **put** it in his mouth, when he threw up."*  or, *"That kid **stuck** it in his mouth and immediately puked."*, etc.

---

Please comment if the above does not address your question.

Comment: @Eirikr Could you give me more rules where a verb before some grammatical expression/in some grammatical pattern MUST be conjugated in the present even if it means the past(at least in English translation)????
I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: @raruna, there are many of these, but I don't have them to mind -- nor can I think of an easy way to search for them. One example is ところ: if you're just about to do something, it's するところ; in the middle of doing it, it's しているところ; just finished doing it, it's したところ. Regardless of whether it's today, yesterday, or tomorrow. See also [this other answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/#answer-16159) which goes into **aspect** (completedness of the action, within the temporal context of the sentence) versus **tense** (when the action occurred relative to the present).